# How to design the following class inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am facing problems about class inheritance design. It is shown in *C++* as follows:

There are 2 kinds of classes, we call them `Object` and `Component` first. 
Class `Object` uses class `Component`, but problem occurs with their subclasses.

For simple, there are 6 classes.

```
class BaseComponent{...};
class ComponentA: public BaseComponent{...};
class ComponentB: public BaseComponent{...};

class BaseObject {
public:
    virtual bool doSomething()=0;
    void setBaseComponent(BaseComponent*c){_c = c;}
    BaseComponent* getBaseComponent()   {return _c;}
private:
    BaseComponent* _c;
}
class ObjectA : public BaseObject {
public:
    bool doSomething(){ /*do someting related to ComponentA*/}
    void setComponentA(ComponentA* a)   {setBaseComponent(a);}
    ComponentA* getComponentA()         
    {return static_cast<ComponentA*>(getBaseComponent());}
}
class ObjectB : public BaseObject {
public:
    bool doSomething(){ /*do someting related to ComponentB*/}
    void setComponentB(ComponentB* b)   {setBaseComponent(b);}
    ComponentB* getComponentB()         
    {return static_cast<ComponentB*>(getBaseComponent());}
}
```

Now the problem comes:

If I do like the above code, I have to check always the class relationship.

(for example, I have to check real class in `ObjectB::getComponentB()` when use `static_cast`)

If I change the code and use `ComponentA` directly in `ObjectA`, I'm abandoning the *"Dependency inversion"*, which makes the code not convenient.

So, could anyone give me some advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So any subclass of `BaseObject` always needs the matching `BaseComponent` subclass?

Make the setter in `BaseObject` protected. It claims that you can give any object any component, and that's a promise the subclasses can't uphold if anyone but them has access to that setter.

Even better would be to make the component a constructor argument, if that's at all possible.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but my post answers it as I understood it.

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian. Your answer  helps me a lot.  For currently, “OjbectA” and "ObjectB" don't have subclasses. So your answer is the right one.  But “ObjectA” and "ComponentA" will both have subclasses one day, the "ComponentA" and “ObjectA” will have the problem "BaseCompoent" and "BaseOjbect" have.  So is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using interfaces instead of concrete classes is that when you use a pointer of the interface you do not have to worry about what is behind.

If you are returning the concrete `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` then you lose that.

Then, IMO, you should change these concrete classes to be able to return a pointer of `BaseComponent` and then you will not need the static_cast.

Comment: Hi, blashser. Thank you for your reply first :)   I need to return "ComponentA" and "ComponentB" directly for that users directly know what kind of class objects they are using. This will save a lot of work that user don't need to check and covert the "BaseComponent" to "ComponentA" or "ComponentB".

Comment: @Laine, then remove methods `set/getBaseComponent` and the member `_c` . Leave only the pure virtual method.